# How to pass a function to a function and access lambda value of passed function in another function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a `fun` which does some work, and updates `progress` while doing work:

```kotlin
fun doSomeWork(/* args, */ progress: (Int) -> Unit) { 
    // ...
}
```

I want to pass `doSomeWork` to another `fun`, by using `block` argument:

```kotlin
helper(/* args */) {
    doSomeWork(/* args */) {
        // it: progress
    }
}
```

But I want to get the `progress` update in `helper` funtion?

```kotlin
fun helper(/* args, */ block: () -> Unit) {
    // ...

    block {
        /* I want progress here? */
    }

    // ...
}
```

I can only edit the `helper` funtion, how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you also edit the caller of `helper`?

Comment: The way you are using `block` in `helper` is incorrect. `block` does not take another lambda as parameter. `block` takes no parameters. What do you actually mean by `block { ... }`?

Comment: I have some other `fun` similar to `doSomeWork` whose last param is `progress`, I want to pass these `fun` somehow in `helper` in such a way that I can get the `progress` update in helper.

Comment: `block { ... }` is what I am not getting what to do there.

Comment: Then no, this is not possible. `helper` doesn't know anything about what is in `block`. It can't be sure that there even ***is*** a `progress` to get. And since you can't change the caller, you can't add/remove/change any parameters of `helper`.

Comment: Yes, you can change the `helper` definition, if thats what you mean by editing the caller of `helper`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235268/discussion-between-sweeper-and-akshdeep-singh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `helper` to accept a `((Int) -> Unit) -> Unit` and change the passed in lambda to invoke that parameter:

```
fun helper(/* args, */ block: ((Int) -> Unit) -> Unit) {
    // ...
    block { progress ->
        val x: Int = progress
        // this will be called every time doSomeWork receives progress from the callback
    }
    // ...
}

fun main() {
    helper { receiveProgress ->
        doSomeWork { progress ->
            receiveProgress(progress)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
fun helper(/* args, */ progress: (Int) -> Unit) {
    // ...

    doSomeWork(/* args, */ ){ p ->
        progress(p)
        //Do something else with p
    }

    // or if you won't want to use the progress in the helper itself:
    doSomeWork(/* args, */ progress)
    // ...
}
```

or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: suppose I have some other function `doSomeWork2`  with different args, but in the last it has `progress` arg, in that case i need to pass `doSomeWork` to `helper`